# phpseclib 2.0 not working after including autoload.php

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm using Composer and this is my first time trying to use phpseclib. I can't find the docs or any wiki about it, it's like there is no information.

I tried searching on stackoverflow but still couldn't get it to work.

This is my .php file:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__ . '/../vendor/phpseclib/');
$loader->register();

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$plaintext = 'terrafrost';

$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);

$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
?>
```

This is the error: `[23-Mar-2020 14:04:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '[23-Mar-2020 00:53:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found in /home/123/domains/asd.com/public_html/Auth/test.php:93`

- This .php is located in: public_html/Auth
- Autoload is located in: public_html/vendor/autoload.php
- Composer folder is located in: public_html/vendor/composer

All I need to do is RSA signing and verifying. Also need to be able to generate a key pair for RSA too.

Please if there is any documentation or wiki about phpseclib tell me. I couldn't find anything on their Github. They link to this page [Sourceforge](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) but it's for 1.0, I only could find 1 example for 2.0. It's like the worst documented library I've ever seen.

If anyone knows a better library please tell me, I'm using this one instead of openssl because I need PSS padding.

Comment: You didn't actually say what the problem you're having is. I can guess, based on the code you posted, but, none-the-less, when posting questions like this in the future, it is something you should do.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the error, wasn't intentional. I will edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you setup Composer correctly, then try this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();

$plaintext = 'terrafrost';

$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);

$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
?>
```

The key difference from the code in your post is that instead of doing `$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();` it's doing `$rsa = new RSA();`. It also removes the unnecessary auto-loading stuff. No doubt you got that extra code from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html but that code doesn't include `__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` - it includes [ClassLoader.php](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) renamed as autoload.php.

> Please if there is any documentation or wiki about phpseclib tell me. I couldn't find anything on their Github. They link to this page Sourceforge but it's for 1.0, I only could find 1 example for 2.0.

When you visit any of the pages with examples you should get a popup that looks like this:

[image]

Select 2.0 and then you'll see examples for 2.0.

> It's like the worst documented library I've ever seen.

I guess you haven't seen https://www.openssl.org/docs/ lol. Anyway, two comments on this:

- if you don't like the documentation you can make improvements yourself to it by making PRs or creating issues at https://github.com/phpseclib/docs
- it is my understanding that for the 3.0 branch the documentation is being rewritten from scratch using https://docusaurus.io/

Comment: Hello, thank you, it fixed it. (had to change '/vendor' to '/../vendor'). Now I have another problem, it says unverified. I checked both keys and they are correct.
Also where can I read about this sign / verify function? I need to change the algorithm, padding, etc.

Comment: Nvm, it took me 1 hour to figure out that I had a typo in my variable name. Sorry.